# App crashing android security exception(missing internet permission?)

Tags: android, permissions, securityexception

So my app has been crashing recently whenever it tries to access internet.

I have already used internet permission in mainfest so im stuck as to what the problem can be

These are my log files

```
 06-05 16:58:47.942 4934-5021/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 4934
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:472)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:258)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:221)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:278)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:216)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:113)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:89)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
                                                                                    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:444)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:258) 
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:221) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:278) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:216) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106) 
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:113) 
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:89) 
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:444) 
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:258) 
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:221) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:278) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:216) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382) 
                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106) 
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:113) 
                                                                                    at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:89) 
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.sunshine.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET."/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set Internet permission with :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET."/>
```

It should be :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: So sorry guys completely forgot